# how do i install an app from the zip file i have?

Tags: zip

How would I install a .zip file from terminal? I'm trying to install an app from a .zip file and when I try change directory (filename) nothing comes up. I know i'm doing something wrong but this is all confusing to me because i'm new.(The file i'm trying to install is called QuestPatcher-ubuntu.zip in https://github.com/Lauriethefish/QuestPatcher/releases/tag/2.2.4 )

Answer (score 3):

You have to download the zip-file, extract it and put to some directory in $PATH variable:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/Lauriethefish/QuestPatcher/releases/download/2.2.4/QuestPatcher-ubuntu.zip
unzip QuestPatcher-ubuntu.zip
chmod +x QuestPatcher 
sudo mv QuestPatcher /usr/local/bin/QuestPatcher
```

then call it from terminal using `QuestPatcher`.